# ::after pseudo-element, a drop down arrow, not displaying on Android

Tags: android, html, css

I have the following markup + CSS which works fine on all desktop browsers, and even sort of okay in Firefox on Android, but the `::after` content doesn't render in Chrome (or the "default" browser) on Android.

Any ideas why this might be?

**Chrome 42.0.2311**
**Android 4.4.3 (HTC One M7)**

**Here's a codepen if it helps:** 
http://codepen.io/sbeliv01/full/LVEQKz/

---

**HTML/CSS**

```css
.contactForm {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contactForm-wrapper {
  padding: 4em;
  background: #efeeee;
}

.contactForm select {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #002d57;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: .5em 2em .5em .5em;
  border: none;
}

.contactForm select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.contactForm .select {
  position: relative;
}

.contactForm .select::after {
  content: "\25BE";
  display: block;
  color: #0084ff;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1.5em;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.contactForm .column {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactForm-wrapper">
    <form class="contactForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column select">
                <select name="co" id="co">
                    <option value="">Select a country...</option>
                    <option value="">Country 1</option>
                    <option value="">Country 2</option>
                    <option value="">Country 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: add `display:block` to the pseudo-element?

Comment: @DerekS Good suggestion but it doesn't seem to have made any difference adding `display: block` to the `::after` element.

Comment: It shows in Chrome on Android for me, it's just very small. Try changing the font size on `::after`

Comment: @Arbel Added `font-size: 16px;`, just to test, and no dice on that either -- I don't see the `::after` element at all. Also added browser + Android version info to post.

Comment: My test is in Chrome 42.0.2311.109 Android 5.1.0. You'd better do mobile Chrome debugging to better understand what's happening in your test conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like older versions of Android are having trouble to display `\25BE` on Chrome, it sounds like a bug. As a workaround you could change it to `\25BC` (similar shape) it then shows up correctly. Alternatively, you could also use font icons.

```css
.u25BE::after {
    content: "\25BE"; 
}
.u25BC::after {
    content: "\25BC"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="u25BE">25BE</div>
<div class="u25BC">25BC</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fbsrmgru/

Comment: Hmm... that does seem to be the case. `\25BC` seems to work while the other does not. I ended up just using `\25BC` and applying `scale(1.75,1)` transform to make it sort of look like the other arrow. http://codepen.io/sbeliv01/full/LVEQKz/